# C#: How do I stop a timer in the middle of a tick

Tags: c#, timer

I set a timer in form1(windows form) to tick every second

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Timer.Interval = 1000;
      Timer.Start;
    }
```

In the timer.tick event, I set it to stop after a certain number of ticks.

```
 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if(x == 0)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("ETC");
           Timer.Stop();
        }
  }
```

However, I found that the timer.Stop() was not ending the timer, and the message box continued popping up one time every second even after x = 0. Why is this? And how do I stop the timer?

Here is the whole code

```
 private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkTiming.Stop();

        try
        {
            timeTick.hour = int.Parse(textBoxHour.Text);
            timeTick.min = int.Parse(textBoxMin.Text);
            timeTick.sec = int.Parse(textBoxSec.Text);
            numRepeat = int.Parse(textBoxRepeat.Text);
            timeTick.totalTime = 0;
            current = timeTick.hour * 3600 + timeTick.min * 60 + timeTick.sec;

            if (timeTick.hour * 3600 + timeTick.min * 60 + timeTick.sec > 0 && timeTick.min <= 60 && timeTick.sec <=60 )
            {

            memory.listHistory.Add(memory.padMultipleString(textBoxHour.Text, textBoxMin.Text, textBoxSec.Text));
            updateListViewHistory(memory.listHistory);

            checkTiming.Interval = 1000;
            checkTiming.Start();      
            }

            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                initialise();
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter positive integers to all textBoxes", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            initialise();
        }
    }
```

And here is the tick event

```
 private void checkTiming_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       timeTick.updateTime(current);
       updateTextBoxes();

       if(current > 0)
       {
           current--;
       }

       if(current == 0)
       {
          if(numRepeat > 1)
          {
              numRepeat--;
              current = timeTick.totalTime;
              //Console.WriteLine(current);

              MessageBox.Show(memory.listHistory.Last() + " has elapsed. " + "Repeating " + numRepeat.ToString() + " more times", "Timing has Ended", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
          }

           if(numRepeat == 1)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(memory.listHistory.Last() + " has elapsed", "Timing has Ended", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
               timeTick.totalTime = 0;
               Console.WriteLine(numRepeat);
               checkTiming.Stop();
           }
       }



   }
```

The main problem is at this part

```
       private void checkTiming_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       timeTick.updateTime(current);
       updateTextBoxes();

       if(current > 0)
       {
           current--;
       }

       if(current == 0)
       {
          if(numRepeat > 1)
          {
              numRepeat--;
              current = timeTick.totalTime;
              //Console.WriteLine(current);

              MessageBox.Show(memory.listHistory.Last() + " has elapsed. " + "Repeating " + numRepeat.ToString() + " more times", "Timing has Ended", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
          }

           if(numRepeat == 1)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(memory.listHistory.Last() + " has elapsed", "Timing has Ended", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
               timeTick.totalTime = 0;
               Console.WriteLine(numRepeat);
               checkTiming.Stop();
           }
       }
```

EVen when numRepeat  is 1 and current = 0, the timer does not stop even when I declared it(checkTiming.Stop())

Comment: What is x here? Does the value of x change?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for us to solve this. That means that we can copy, paste, and run your code and see your problem for ourselves. We can't do that with the code you've posted.

Comment: are you killing timer in same form or from another form?

Comment: Ok, I added the whole part here.

Comment: Stop the timer before you show the message box. MessageBox.Show will block and pump window messages which will allow the timer to fire again.

Comment: Ok, Let me try that. Edit: Thanks Alois Kraus. That worked

Comment: Not that this is an answer to your question, but you should learn to avoid `int.Parse` and use `int.TryParse` instead. Then you can get rid of your terrible `try`/`catch` block and write clearer and cleaner code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx), `MessageBox`:

> Displays a message window, also known as a dialog box, which presents a message to the user. It is a modal window, **blocking other actions in the application** until the user closes it.

This means that when control reaches the `MessageBox.Show` line, it stops there until the user closes the message box. This means that `Timer.Stop` will not be called until the user closes the message box. This is why the timer will still tick.

To fix this, just change the order of the method calls:

```
   checkTiming.Stop();
   MessageBox.Show(memory.listHistory.Last() + " has elapsed", "Timing has Ended", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
   timeTick.totalTime = 0;
   Console.WriteLine(numRepeat);
```